# Java parsefloat same result on every CPU

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I just read about strictfp (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp) and the fact that floating / double point operations may yield different results on different CPUs since Java 1.2.

Now I wonder if the same is true for `Float.valueOf` method?
I cannot find any source to this. The javadoc for `valueOf` explicitly states that:

```
Note that the round-to-nearest rule also implies overflow and underflow behaviour;
```

Which to me indicates that it may be different if strictfp is turned off.

Is there a source that is exact on this topic and states that this is the case or not?

Comment: Not using strictfp allows one to use the chips floating point support, say 10 bytes i.o. 8 bytes for a double for intermediate calculations. So `Float.valueOf` might use better precision, but the resulting 4 byte float will probably not markedly differ. _Not 100% sure._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which to me indicates that it may be different if strictfp is turned off.

The JLS says that the meaning of the `strictfp` modifier is that any expressions within the class or method are evaluated as FP-strict.

However, JLS doesn't say that if you call a different method in an FP-strict expressions that the calculations in that method are automatically FP-strict as well.

This means that the result you get from a call to `Float.valueOf` doesn't depend on `strictfp` / the FP-strictness of the caller.

The flipside is that the (internal) Java class that does the conversion in `Float.valueOf(String)`:

- takes care to use specific values for INF and NaN values,
- takes care to ensure that the value is within the error bounds set out in the javadoc, and
- in the `Float` case, it does the conversion in `double` arithmetic.

However, the conversion method is not a `strictfp` method, so if the code was sensitive to FP-strictness, then there would be a problem.

The class to look for is `jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal` in Java 11.